# Argument of length 0 in for loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have two data frames (`eeg` and `p1_1_a`) and an empty list (`list`):

```
> head(eeg)
  wave_1
1 18.959
2 19.432
3 20.384
4 20.489
5 21.012
6 21.571

> nrow(eeg)
[1] 849

> head(p1_1_a)
      Time  Latency Amplitude Peak_Lenght
1  57.1184  7.90738 -0.388889     8.44690
2 123.3470 15.49230 -0.917778     5.51634
3 191.0920 11.87220 -0.466667     6.55066
4 249.1710 15.49230 -0.871111     5.68873
5 325.5090 10.32080 -0.388889     5.34396
6 385.6040 12.56180 -0.684444     4.82680

> nrow(p1_1_a)
[1] 10

> list <- c()
```

I want to create a list that consists of the values from `eeg$wave_1` that are the closest smaller values to each of the values in `p1_1_a$Time`. So for the first index in `p1_1_a$Time` which has the value 57.1184, the closest smaller value in eeg$wave_1 would be 56.678 (index 48). So the final list would have 10 rows with values from `eeg$wave_1`.

I have written this loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(p1_1_a$Time)){
  if(eeg$wave_1 <= p1_1_a$Time[i]){
    list <- max(eeg$wave_1 <= p1_1_a$Time[i])
  }
}
```

But I get the error:

> Error in 1:nrow(p1_1_a$Time) : argument of length 0

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please make your data (easily) reproducible by using `dput(head(eeg))`.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

`nrow` is a function to be called on a data frame. `p1_1_a` is a data frame. `p1_1_a$Time` is a list.

`nrow(p1_1_a$Time)` evaluates to NULL, so your error message is telling you that. This makes sense if you try:

```
for(i in 1:NULL){
  print(i)
}
```

Expect to see:

> Error in 1:NULL : argument of length 0

### Solution 1

You can re-write your loop to use `length` instead of `nrow` since you're looping over a list (a column in a data frame is a list):

```
for(i in 1:length(p1_1_a$Time)){
  if(eeg$wave_1 <= p1_1_a$Time[i]){
    list <- max(eeg$wave_1 <= p1_1_a$Time[i])
  }
}
```

### Solution 2

You can also re-write your loop to use `nrow` on the data frame since it's a function to be called on a data frame (and not on a list):

```
for(i in 1:nrow(p1_1_a)){
  if(eeg$wave_1 <= p1_1_a$Time[i]){
    list <- max(eeg$wave_1 <= p1_1_a$Time[i])
  }
}
```